# Why am I receiving a XamlParseException on my BindingContext?

Tags: xamarin.forms, f#

I can't understand why I'm receiving a XAML parsing error:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 8:10. Type
>   uilogic:ViewModel1 not found in xmlns
>   clr-namespace:Nikeza.Mobile.UILogic.Registration;assembly=Nikeza.Mobile.UILogic
>   occurred

[image]

I know for a fact that my namespace declaration is correct because IntelliSense displays the class name as a suggestion when I'm setting my binding-context.

[image]

Here's the view-model that I'm trying to bind to:

[image]

The following attempts have failed:

1. deleted obj and bin folders
2. Rebooted machine

Comment: That's because I updated the namespace name and didn't update the screenshot I had posted. Good catch.

Comment: Is it in the same assembly or it's a `dll` reference?

Comment: It's in a separate library (i.e. DLL reference).

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code and error messages, since this renders the questions way less searchable.

Answer (score 1):

**Just Try:**
*xmlns:registration="clr-namespace:Nikeza.Mobile.UILogic.Registration"*